# Adding a SVG doc from a String to a SVG document using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, internet-explorer-9

I need to add a node to a svg file which is on a html page when I call the function `pinta(strSVG)`.
This SVG file is embed on the html page on a `<object>` tag

SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11-flat-20030114.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" height="100%" width="100%" onload="inicia(evt)" >

<script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[      

parent.pinta=pinta

function inicia(event){
    SVGDocument =  event.target.ownerDocument;                                 
}

function pinta(strSVG){
    xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async=false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(strSVG);
    var newNode=xmlDoc.element;
    SVGDocument.getElementById('grafico1').appendChild(newNode);
}
]]></script>
<svg y="" width="" height="" id="grafico1"/>
<svg y="500" width="" height="" id="grafico2"/>
<g id="tip_Cuadro"/>
<g id="tip_texto"/>
</svg>
```

returns a invalid argument

The call to pinta(strSVG) is on the webpage HTML:

```
var object = document.getElementById('tbl27svg');
var svgdoc = object.contentDocument;
if (svgdoc && svgdoc.defaultView)
    svgwin = svgdoc.defaultView;
    else if (object.window)
        svgwin = object.window;
       else try {
        svgwin = object.getWindow();
      }
  catch(exception) {
    alert('The DocumentView interface is not supported\r\n' +
          'Non-W3C methods of obtaining "window" also failed');
  }
svgwin.pinta(str);
```

str contains the complete svg doc:

```
"<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">" ......
```

The problem is pinta can't receive srtSVG. srtSVG is undefined on pinta(srtSVG) function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlDoc.documentElement, 'application/xml');

document.getElementById('grafico1').appendChild(
 document.getElementById('grafico1').ownerDocument.importNode(doc.documentElement, true));
```

newNode is not a single element it's a complete document containing potentially many elements and appendChild is only for adding a single element by its tag name.

Comment: Thanks Robert. But: DOM Exception:SYNTAX_ERR (12)  `var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlDoc.documentElement, 'application/xml');` I think this is no valid for IE9...wich only aceppts `xmlDoc.loadXML(strSVG);`, ??

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/15/domparser-and-xmlserializer-in-ie9-beta.aspx

Comment: Yes, I think the problem is I can't send the SVG document through  the strSVG parameter. Because if I make: alert(srtSVG) I get undefined srtSVG....